# Google maps unavailable issue solved by playing Spotify or Amazon Music first

Tags: usb-connection-mode

I am frequently facing this issue.

1. I would connect my Android 10 phone to our 2021 RAV4 Android Auto USB.
2. Then Google Maps would close up on my phone.
3. While that happens, the RAV4 console would notify blue tooth disconnected and Android Auto connected. Wait till these messages are completed.
4. But when I click on the RAV4 console Map button, the console would notify that no Map application was available or that Android Auto disconnected.

But fear not, I have a way to solve the Maps availability issue by taking these steps.

1. Connect my phone to the RAV4 Android Auto USB.
2. Ensure I do not press the Map button on the RAV4 console yet.
3. Play Spotify or Amazon Music on my phone first.
4. Then press the Map button on the RAV4 console.

Questions:

1. What is Google doing wrong that Spotify or Amazon Music is doing right?
2. What are the protocol disconnects between my phone and the RAV4 Android Auto that is causing these frequent disconnects. Feel free to refer me to other StackOverflow coding sites.

Comment: Sounds to me like Google Maps is not closing but the app is crashing. The question why this happens is difficult may be it was used in an unexpected way or some other problem occurred. If you connect the phone directly after this happens to a PC and check `adb logcat` may be you may find an error message and a stack trace.